# How to extract the common part between two audio signals and remove it from the signal?

Tags: signal-processing, audio-processing, deconvolution, frequency-domain

If I have two audio signals Y1 and Y2 in Fourier domain that are the results of multiplication of S with H1 and H2 respectively (convolution in time domain):

Y1=H1*S

Y2=H2*S

And **I don't have S and H1, H2**, but I know that S is the same in both Y1 and Y2. Is there a good way to extract S out to only have H1 and H2 in the right side of the equation?

thanks

Comment: So you have many examples or just these two?

Comment: Can you stimulate the systems that produced Y1 and Y2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like two equations with three variables. I don't think that you can extract the original signal, S.

Comment: Sure. But I was thinking of more like a blind deconvolution that can get benefit from having two signals with a mutual signal in them.

Comment: As long as I know, blind separation helps separate the signal to components but does not alow reconstruction of the original input

Comment: Mainly my purpose was to get rid of the S and to have just the H. But fortunately, I don’t need to do that anymore! Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

I was asking myself the same question. My first approach was to do a crosscorellation between the signals, to get the point where they are most similar. then I padded one of the two so they are exactly "time synchronous", meaning the main sound source was exactly centered. I then substracted the one from the other. I think this is a valid approach, although I didn't follow through on it and its not working properly. If youve got additional ideas, let me know ;)